# Troubles installing redmine on linux server Ubuntu 22.04.4

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, redmine

I made this install

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-passenger
```

After that, I configured the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
  PassengerDefaultUser www-data
</IfModule>
```

Also I created a symbolic link for REDMINE

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/html/redmine
```

Passenger is enabled

```
sudo a2enmod passenger
```

This is my configuration of `sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
  RailsBaseURI /redmine
  PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/redmine/
</Directory>
```

When I start my web-browser, I get this error:

[image]

I also add information from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

[image: error.log 1]

[image: error.log 2]

[image: error.log 3]

[image: error.log 4]